# Diferença na Declaração de uma Classe @GeneratedValue

Tags: java

Qual a diferença quando eu declaro uma classe informando o 
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`) e não informando, visto que o gerenciador de banco de dados que vai coordenar a chave primária?
Estou perguntando pois informando ou não, criou as tabelas da mesma forma.

```
@Entity
public class Status implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="status_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="status_descricao")
    private String descricao;**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tabela é criada normalmente sem a anotação `@GeneratedValue`, mas quando for inserir um registro, o valor do campo que corresponde a chave primária deve ser atribuido manualmente, pois quando você usa o `@GeneratedValue`, automaticamente o valor da coluna é incrementado.

No seu caso, o campo `id` é incrementado automaticamente toda vez que um novo registro é inserido, isso por causa da anotação. Caso não use, toda vez é necessário definir um valor único para a coluna.

Exemplo:

```
Status status = new Status();
status.setId(1);
status.setDescricao("Primeira objeto com id manual");

Status statusObj = new Status();
statusObj.setId(2);
statusObj.setDescricao("Segundo objeto com id manual");
```

Comment: Eu percebi isso mesmo. No momento de teste com o Postman, caso não exista a anotação @GeneratedValue os dados não são inseridos no banco de dados. Depois e colocar esta anotação quanto envio um POST via Postman ele consegue gravar no banco de dados. Muito obrigado